# Auto refresh using Task

Tags: c#, charts, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a winforms application with a chart component working pretty well and now I need to implement a auto refresh mechanism, so the chart will be updated continuously in a time frame setted by the user in run time (30 segs, 1 min,...).
I'm searching how to use Task to get this, but I noticed the Task doesn't have a timer.

So, have you already done something similar? What sounds the best approach? Threads? BackGroundWorker?

My project is .NET 4.0 and I can't modify it.

Comment: Cant you just use normal timers?

Comment: @Koen I'm not sure because I cant block the UI and also I'm looking for the best performance possible

Comment: What is this task going to do, CPU bound work?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, that is the point!

Comment: Please include [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear at all from your question what you are trying to do. Is there some computation that is literally running continuously, and which you periodically want to display the results of on the screen? Or do you just want to periodically run the computation and then update the screen based on the result?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I mean.. I need to refresh a chart on the screen (winforms), so the code will invoke a WS and populate a datatable which is binded to a chart. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Sorry...there's still no code here. And it's still not clear what operation(s) you need to happen periodically and what the operation's(s') relationship to the chart is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write that yourself, based on `Task.Delay` (which internally uses a `System.Threading.Timer`) that creates a task that completes after a certain time:

```
async Task AutoRefresh(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        RefreshChart();
        await Task.Delay(interval);
    }
}
```

You can call it at startup with the specific interval and a `CancellationToken` to signal when it should stop. This will return a task you can `await` at the end to make sure you don't have any unhandled exceptions:

```
// start
var interval = GetIntervalFromUser();
_cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
_autoRefreshTask = AutoRefresh(interval, cts.Token);

// end
_cts.Cancel();
try
{
    await _autoRefreshTask;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

---

You can use `async-await` in .Net 4.0 with the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

Comment: @l3arnon, initially it's what I was trying to do.. using `Task` with `Timer` object. I'm going to test this approach.. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In WPF we have DispatchTimers but sadly I don't think you can use them with WinForms. You might be able to do something clever with a System.Threading.Timer (which can be used off the GUI thread) and an invoke of some sort to the GUI thread when you're ready to update it. Would that be something like what you need to do?

Comment: yes. I've already checked the System.Threading.Timer but my concern is regarding to performance at all. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, if you're using System.Threading.Timer and not the winforms timer you can handle things off the GUI thread. If you mean "which construct is faster" as far as I know it will come down to what you're doing, not which threading construct you use. Clarification on the issue?

Comment: Winforms has `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. It's exactly like `DispatcherTimer`, but for Winforms instead.

Comment: Are you sure about that peter? I was under the impression System.Windows.Forms.Timer is only on the GUI thread. DispatchTimer can be passed a thread to work on instead. Which is why i suggested System.Threading.Timer which allows the same thing.

Comment: Sorry...I may have misunderstood your intent (but then, that would suggest the answer should be written more clearly ;) ). Yes, Winforms timer event happens in the GUI thread; that's the reason for using it, so that you can execute things that are supposed to happen in the GUI thread. IMHO, there's no reason to use `DispatcherTimer` unless the need is also to execute the timer event on the GUI thread, hence my inference that's what you meant.